# Extracting only values from bag of words

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, series

I have written some code that takes an input csv and converts it into JSON using pandas. I need some help with formatting.

input

```
Serial UID,Sample ID,For Serial Name,Rev Serial Name
14,10882401,0014F,0014R
18,10881462,0018F,0018R
```

current-output

```
{
    "Serial": "0018F - 0018R",
    "Barcode UID": "18",
    "Sample ID": "10881462"
}
```

required-output

```
{
    "Serials": {
        "0018F - 0018R" : {
            "Barcode UID": "18",
            "Sample ID": "10881462"
            }
        {
        "0014F - 0014R" :{
            "Barcode UID": "14",
            "Sample ID": "10882401",
        }
    }
}
```

```py
import pandas as pd
import csv
import json
from itertools import groupby 
from collections import OrderedDict

df = pd.read_csv(f'{my_name}.csv', dtype={
            "Barcode UID" : str,
            "Sample ID" : str,
            "For Serial Name" : str,
            "Rev Serial Name" : str
        })

results = []
temp_serials  = []
count = 0


for (barcode_uid, sample_id), bag in df.groupby(["Barcode UID", "Sample ID"]):
    contents_df = bag.drop(["Barcode UID", "Sample ID"], axis=1)
    subset = [OrderedDict(row) for i,row in contents_df.iterrows()]

    for i in subset:
        (key, val) = i.items()
        temp_barcodes.append("{} - {}".format(key[1],val[1]))

    results.append(OrderedDict([
        ("Barcodes", temp_barcodes[count]),
        ("Barcode UID", barcode_uid),
        ("Sample ID", sample_id)
        ]))
    count+=1



print(json.dumps(results, indent=4))
```

Actual/expected outputs shown. Just need to better format my json, confused as to how to do that with an orderedDict.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `dict.values()`?  Here's an example:

```
d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30}
for value in d.values():
    print(value)
# 10
# 20
# 30
```

Comment: What type of answer is this anyway? I'm asking some complicated stuff and you showing me how to print values?